# Where am I supposed to check on input data?

Tags: validation, oop

I started to think of when should I check the input data. I'm in this scenario:

```
class Father
{
    string name;
    public Father(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
}

class Child extends Father
{
    private Child(string n)
    {
        base(n);
    }

    public NewChild(string n)
    {
        return new Child(n);
    }
}
```

Let's say I want to check if the string that comes from outside is not null and at least 5 chars long.
Where should I do the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Father` class should check it as a precondition in the constructor and throw an exception if the input is not valid.